# Can not pass a string var into a `option.setName()` function in discord.js

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Hello this is my code for some reason when I pass `optName` into `option.setName()` on line 22 I get this error.

[image]

How ever when I pass something like `"test"` into `option.setName()` everything works fine so does any one have any idea what is wrong?

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";
import { optionsI } from "./interfaces";

function initOptions(
    slashCommandBuild: SlashCommandBuilder,
    options: optionsI,
) {
    for (const [keys, values] of Object.entries(options) as [
        keys: keyof typeof options,
        values: Map<string, string>,
    ][]) {
        slashCommandBuild[keys]((option: any) => {
            const optName: string = values.keys().next().value;
            const optDesc: string | undefined = values.get(
                values.keys().next().value,
            );
            if (optName === undefined || optName === null) {
                throw new Error(
                    `Please make sure that the command has a name.`,
                );
            }
            option.setName(optName);

            if (optDesc === null || optDesc === undefined) return option;
            option.setDescription(optDesc);

            return option;
        });
    }
}

export { initOptions };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slash command names and option names have to be lowercase (and have no spaces). You can instead pass the string `"opt-name"`.

[Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object-application-command-naming) shows the regex for command names.

> `CHAT_INPUT` command names and command option names must match the following regex `^[-_\p{L}\p{N}\p{sc=Deva}\p{sc=Thai}]{1,32}$` with the unicode flag set.